# Unable to browse or curl VPN internal domain but nslookup works

Tags: dns, fedora, cisco-vpn-client

I'm using Fedora 24 built in Cisco IPSec VPN client.  I can connect and ssh into VPN instances.

I an also nslookup office domains.  However browsing office site and `curl` return domain not found.

I tried adding routes and I checked `/etc/resolv.conf` and they are set correctly. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post the output when you try curl and also the contents of `route -n` and `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @MarkoPolo many thanks but I resolved this.  Turns out it's a entry in `nsswitch.conf` and also the URL is `.local` based which causes more problems